# SignalR without MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, signalr

I've just gone through the tutorials on MVC4 + SignalR but my existing site is in Web Pages framework, can we use ASP.NET SignalR with an ASP.NET WebPages (WebMatrix)-based site instead of MVC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use SignalR with ASP.NET WebPages (WebMatrix). SignalR has no dependency on ASP.NET MVC, but it does rely on using jQuery.

Read [SignalR And Knockout In ASP.NET Web Pages Using WebMatrix](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/206/SignalR-And-Knockout-In-ASP.NET-Web-Pages-Using-WebMatrix) for a walkthrough of using SignalR with ASP.NET WebPages (WebMatrix).

Comment: SignalR only has a dependency on jquery if your client is a webpage.  If your client is WPF, or even Windows Phone, based, there is obviously no jquery dependency.

Comment: @JonB - correct, but the OP was asking in the context of doing web development, point taken though. :-)